# MLflow: how to return experiment status as failed

Tags: machine-learning, mlflow

I have written out my code and it has the following form

```
def train(run_name, log_basepath, logger, parameters):

    try:
        metrics = training_functions(parameters) # <---- code that can fail

        # demo for up loading attributes to a given run
        with mlflow.start_run(run_name=run_name):

            # log parameters
            mlflow.log_params(parameters)

            # log metrics
            mlflow.log_metrics(metrics)

            # define experiment tags
            mlflow.set_tags(tags)

            # upload pertinent files
            mlflow.log_artifact(artifact_abspath)

            # main model files
            mlflow.log_artifact(log_basepath)

    except Exception as e:
        logger.error('\nFailed model training. Returned following error:\n {} \n\n'.format(e))
        logger.info( 'Error on line {}'.format(sys.exc_info()[-1].tb_lineno))

        # demo for up loading attributes to a given run
        with mlflow.start_run(run_name=run_name):
            # define run tags
            logger.info('experiment name: {}'.format(experiment_name))
            logger.info('run_name: {}'.format(run_name))
            logger.info('run failed')

            mlflow.log_artifact(log_basepath)
```

my aim is to send the logs to the mlflow server if there is a failure. My questions is, how do I get mlflow to mark this as a failure?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `mlfow.set_tag("LOG_STATUS", "FAILED")`